# How do Javascript object instances retain methods after parent class is redefined?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to understand Javascript prototypal inheritance and am having trouble understanding the relationship between object instances and their respective classes' prototype property which stores inherited methods.

I understand that defining methods in a class's prototype property allows for instances to access/inherit these methods so that methods are not redefined. Presumably this is achieved by allowing the instance a pointer to the method in memory (or something much akin to this). I also understand why adding methods to a class's prototype property allows previously created instances access to these "new" methods, since the instances are simply accessing their prototype property (which includes the class they derive from) which in turn accesses the class's prototype property.

What I *do not* understand is the following scenario:

1. I define a trivial object with method:

   ```
   function Person(name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
     return "Hello, " + this.name;
   }
   ```
2. I create an instance and can access data:

   ```
   var p = new Person("Ryan");
   p.name //"Ryan"
   p.greeting() //"Hello, Ryan"
   ```
3. I *redefine* Person *without* greeting:

   ```
   Person = function (name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   ```
4. I can still use the greeting on the previous instance:

   `p.greeting() //"Hello, Ryan" but expected error`

If as Person is being redefined it overwrites the prior Person constructor in memory, how is it that the instance "p" can still access the greeting method if there is no longer any such method associated with Person? Is it the case that instances actually copy the location of their inherited classes' methods in their own prototype field? If this is the case, why is it that there is always talk of a "prototype chain" that the processor must "walk up" to find inherited methods if the instance stores the location of these methods directly in their own prototype field?

Help is much appreciated. I apologize if there is something simple that I missed.

Comment: You're just creating a new class (and overwrite the variable `Person`), but you don't change the class that `p` is an instance of or the prototype from which it inherits.

Comment: @Bergi That makes sense as a description of what's going on, but I don't understand why the same area of memory is not overwritten - I suppose this is functionality that is special to objects and such data types since JS developers anticipated rewriting of functions? Because if I assigned an integer to a variable and reassigned the variable, the same location in memory would be used no? Or is the original location of the function above not rewritten because there is still an active pointer to it and so the memory is off limits for newly requested memory?

Comment: Objects in JS don't have a fixed location, you cannot overwrite them. The variable only contains a reference to the object (or function object, in this case) somewhere in memory. Creating a new function allocates new memory somewhere else, and assigning to the variable just changes the reference stored in that variable. Other things (like your `p` instance) still reference the old object. JavaScript is an object-oriented, garbage-collected language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up names which point to objects and the objects themselves. When you use:

```
Person = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

you are *not* redefining the object that the name `Person` points to. You are just taking the name `Person` and pointing it to a new thing — a new function. The old `Person.protoype` is still in memory and the instance `p` holds a reference to it and `p.constructor` still points to the original `Person` function.

You can confirm this by grabbing a reference of the Person.prototype and comparing before and after the reassignment of the variable `Person`

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
  return "Hello, " + this.name;
}
var p = new Person("Ryan");

// p's prototype is Person.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === Person.prototype) // true

// grab a reference of the protoype for later
let Pprotot = Person.prototype

// point variable Person at something else
Person = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
}

// p's prototype is STILL the old Person.prototype
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(p) === Pprotot)    // still true

// p also still holds a reference to the old function (through the prototype)
console.log(p.constructor)

// but it's not the same thing the variable Person now points to
console.log(p.constructor === Person)
```

Comment: The __proto__ field in any given instance then stores a reference/pointer to the prototype of the most direct parent object it inherited from and from this location in memory another __proto__ field can be accessed to move up the chain until Object is reached, correct? My only other question, then, is why do I see method declarations returned with Object.getPrototypeOf(p)? This returns: Person {greeting: function} but I expected inherited methods to be *within* Person's prototype field, not the instance's __proto__ field (Object.getPrototypeOf([]) does not return a list of array methods).

Comment: @soporific312 No, it's not the `.__proto__` property that stores this, it's an internal field that should be accessed with `Object.getPrototypeOf`. The `__proto__` getter is deprecated. But yes, this thing defines the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @soporific312 `console.log`ing the prototype shows the `Person.prototype` object - you can log that directly to see it's the same. Notice that logging the `Array.prototype` doesn't show any methods because they are not enumerable, but they are still there.

Comment: @soporific312 you can get a better idea of what's on the array prototype with `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf([])))` This will list the methods.

Comment: @Bergi This is really helpful--thanks. I saw that __proto__ is deprecated - is the internal field only accessible by the Object.getPrototypeOf getter then? I don't understand what you mean by "*because* they are not enumerable" - the greeting function is not enumerable either?

Comment: @soporific312 Yes, only `Object.getPrototypeOf`. Regarding [enumerability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties), the `greeting` property of your custom prototype is enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a little test and it seems like the variable p is still remembering the previous object.

```
Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
const s = new Person('hello');
s.name; //hello
s.greeting(); //s.greeting is not a function
```

Comment: Yes it does remember the previous object - as Mark Meyer mentioned the previously made object still points to the place in memory where the original object was defined.